# How to optionally pass arguments with non-default values in Python?

Tags: python, syntactic-sugar

I have a following method:

```
def a(b='default_b', c='default_c', d='default_d'):
    # …
    pass
```

And I have some command-line interface that allows either to provide variables `user_b`, `user_c`, `user_d` or to set them to `None` - i.e. the simple Python `argparse` module.

I want to make a call like:

```
a(b=user_b if user_b is not None,
  c=user_c if user_c is not None,
  d=user_d if user_d is not None)
```

If the variable is `None` I want to use a default value from the method's argument.

The only way I found is to check all the combinations of the user variables:

```
if not user_b and not user_c and not user_d:
    a()
elif not user_b and not user_c and user_d:
    a(d)
…
elif user_b and user_c and user_d:
    a(b, c, d)
```

What is more efficient, fancy and Pythonic way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
arg_dict = {}
if user_b is not None:
    arg_dict["b"] = user_b
if user_c is not None:
    arg_dict["c"] = user_c
if user_d is not None:
    arg_dict["d"] = user_d

a(**arg_dict)
```

Not exactly pretty though.

A nicer way would just be to re-write your function `a` to accept `None` as a default answer, and then check for that. (I.e. `if b is None: b = "default_b"`)

Comment: Building the `dict` could be a little more succinct with: `arg_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(('b', 'c', 'd'), (user_b, user_c, user_d)) if v is not None}` but yeah, it's never going to be really pretty.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that filters out unwanted values then use it to scrub the target function call.

```
def scrub_params(**kw):
    return {k:v for k,v in kw.items() if v is not None}

some_function(**scrub_params(foo=args.foo, bar=args.bar))
```

Comment: A decorator that does this might be even nicer.

Comment: Also, at least on Python 3, I think you'd need to use `kw.items()` instead of `kw`.

Comment: @tagc - you are absolutely right. I fixed the bug but snce you've jumped in and done the decorator, I'll leave that one to you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight variation of [tdelaney's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39878272/1636276) (+1 to it for starting me off) that works by *decorating* `a` with another function that removes all keyword arguments passed to the decoratee that have a value of `None`.

```
from functools import wraps


# You can reuse this decorator for all functions that might be
# invoked in your CLI that should handle their arguments like
# 'a' does.
def scrub_parameters(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(**kwargs):
        kwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None}
        return f(**kwargs)

    return wrapper


@scrub_parameters
def a(b='default_b', c='default_c', d='default_d'):
    print('b={}, c={}, d={}'.format(b, c, d))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arg_dict = {'b': 'user_b', 'c': 'user_c', 'd': None}
    a(**arg_dict)  # b=user_b, c=user_c, d=default_d

    arg_dict = {'b': None, 'c': 'user_c', 'd': None}
    a(**arg_dict)  # b=default_b, c=user_c, d=default_d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class with your data and pass the object as argument.

```
class Args:
    def __init__(self, user_b, user_c, user_d):
        self.b = user_b
        self.c = user_c
        self.d = user_d
```